# ArrayOutofBoundsException e

Tags: java

Which type of exception is occurs in this code.
Why the catch statement is not taking `ArrayOutofBoundsException e`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i,j,k,n,m,l,x,y;

    Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
    n=sc.nextInt();
    ArrayList [] a=new ArrayList[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        m=sc.nextInt();
       a[i]=new ArrayList();
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            a[i].add(sc.nextInt());
        } 
    }
    k=sc.nextInt();
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
        x=sc.nextInt();
        y=sc.nextInt();
        try
            {
            System.out.println(a[x-1].get(y-1));
        }
        catch(ArrayOutofBoundsException e)
            {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the exception?

Comment: check it properly... its catching the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Array of ArrayList in your program,

From the java doc an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)'s get method

> Throws:
>       IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

and

> All array accesses are checked at run time; an attempt to use an index
>   that is less than zero or greater than or equal to the length of the
>   array causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to be thrown.

So you try to catch [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) in your program along with [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

Ex:

```
try {
    System.out.println(a[x - 1].get(y - 1));
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR!");
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR! IndexOutOfBoundsException ");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion